# Find duplicate letters in two different strings

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

My program asks the user to input first name then last name. How can I make it find the duplicate letters from first and last name? and if there is none it will print "no duplicate value in First and Last name"

here is my code but i need the output to be "the duplicate characters... is/are ['a', 'b', 'c']". and also when there is no duplicate my code prints multiple "No duplicate value in First name and Last name" but i need it to be one only.

```
for fl in firstName: 
    if fl in lastName:
       print("The duplicate character in your First name and Last name is/are: ", tuple(fl))
    
    else:
       print("No duplicate value in First name and Last name")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do so,

```
first_name = 'john'
last_name = 'Doe'

for letter in first_name:
        if letter in last_name:
                print(letter)
```